# Conditional percentiles in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, percentile

I'm trying find various percentiles of a range conditional on the data in a corresponding column being equal to a value. I've tried many different combinations, but I just keep getting different errors. This is where I am at so far:

```
Sub ConditionalPercentiles()
    'I need to write a procedure which find the percentile of column J conditional on the values in K
    Dim BK1, BK3, M3 As String
    Dim P99_7, P0_3 As Single
    Dim MyArray As Range
    Dim Data As Variant
    'Not sure if results and func need to be Dim-ed as variant
    Set Data = Range("J7:K1564")

    M3 = 3
    BK1 = "BK1"
    BK3 = "BK1"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Data
        .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=M3
        'This correctly finds the range I want
        MyArray = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        'The problem is that the AutoFilter method above finds the necassary conditional area _
        'but I then have to capture that conditional range somehow in order to input it into _
        'the percentile function
        P99_7 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(MyArray, 0.997)
        'I only want to input the conditional data into the percentile calculation
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You used `DataBodyRange`. Your data lie in a table?

Comment: My data isn't in a pivot table or anything, it's just in a range, but yes I am not sure whether that is the correct way to go about it

Comment: You'll have to loop to create an array from a filtered range.